# jQuery / datatables: update rank column after sort & page

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

The first column of a table has its rank in the current sort order. I update it after sorting (easy) but cannot figure out how to access the current page # and size of page to update it for the 2nd, 3rd, etc page. I have..

```
        $("table.datatable")
            .dataTable({
                fnDrawCallback: function() {
                    $(this).find("td.counter span").each(function(i, row) {
                        $(this).html(i + 1);
                        // Should be something like
                        // $(this).html(dataTable.pageno + dataTable.pagesize + i)
                    });
                }
            });
```

What's the proper way of getting the page # and page size to do that so the first row on the second page is #11 (if it's 10 per page)?

**UPDATE** ended up doing this; not sure how "proper" it is, but..

```
fnDrawCallback: function(settings) {
    $(this).find("td.counter span").each(function(i, row) {
        $(this).html(i + 1 + settings._iDisplayStart);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this example on the Datatables documentation, which adds an index column to your table:

http://datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/api/counter_column.html